# Converting array to polyline using Arcade with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, length, array, arcade

Arcade/ArcGIS Pro 2.9:

I have an array of polyline vertices:

```
[[[670634.3148,4862051.3579,null],[670719.3321,4862051.0072,null],[670721.44381227,4862055.2956567,null],
[670724.26721751,4862059.1529319,null],[670727.71675869,4862062.4621395,null],[670731.6879051,4862065.1230012,null],
[670736.06031997,4862067.0548856,null],[670740.70150695,4862068.1992512,null],[670745.47082515,4862068.5214206,null],
[670750.22375097,4862068.011631,null],[670754.81625751,4862066.6853305,null],[670759.10917905,4862064.5827098,null],
[670762.97242811,4862061.7674841,null],[670766.2889375,4862058.3249626,null],[670768.95820776,4862054.3594632,null],
[670770.89935255,4862049.9911516,null],[670772.0535498,4862045.3523998,null],[670772.38582412,4862040.583775,null],
[670771.88610666,4862035.8297796,null],[670770.56954026,4862031.2344731,null],[670768.47602054,4862026.9371059,null],
[670765.66898698,4862023.0679004,null],[670762.2335005,4862019.7441041,null],[670758.27366592,4862017.0664373,null],
[670753.90947724,4862015.1160409,null],[670749.27318152,4862013.9520171,null],[670744.50527143,4862013.6096393,null],
[670739.75022791,4862014.0992824,null],[670735.15214202,4862015.4061089,null],[670730.85034857,4862017.4905182,null],
[670726.97520385,4862020.289347,null],[670723.64413555,4862023.717783,null],[670720.95808431,4862027.6719349,null],
[670718.99844495,4862032.0319811,null],[670717.8246,4862036.6658,null]]]
```

I want to convert the array to a polyline so that I can use Arcade geometry functions on it.

I've searched the docs, but I can't seem to find an Arcade function that converts an array to a polyline. I see there is a `FromJSON()` function, but I don't think my array is JSON. And I don't see a `FromArray()` function in the docs.

---

How can I convert the array to a polyline using Arcade?

Comment: Where is this array coming from? What mechanism is generating it? If it is being generated in a python environment you could use arcpy to create a polyline geometry.

Comment: What the `paths` property of the `Polyline` object is giving you is the same paths that is set in JSON to pass to the Polyline constructor.  Take what you have and embed it into JSON structure and add a `"spatialReference"` property, and then pass it to Polyline constructor.

Comment: @bixb0012 Thanks! For my notes, I think this is what you're referring to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KTZU.png 

Source: [Arcade Polyline Function](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#polyline)

Comment: @User1974, I can a bit later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Polyline | Geometry Functions | ArcGIS Arcade](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#polyline):

> **Polyline(definition) -> Polyline**
>
> Constructs a Polyline object from a JSON string or an object literal.  The
> JSON schema must follow the ArcGIS REST API format for Polyline geometries.

and looking at  [Geometry objects -- Common Data Types | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/geometry-objects.htm)

> **Polyline**
>
> A polyline (specified as esriGeometryPolyline) contains an array of paths
> or curvePaths and a spatialReference. ... Each path is represented as
> an array of points, and each point in the path is represented as an array
> of numbers.

Given an array of coordinates that is compatible/compliant with JSON formatting, one can directly embed the array into a larger JSON definition for the polyline object.

```
// array of coordinates that is compliant with JSON formatting
var paths = [
    [[-97.06138,32.837],[-97.06133,32.836],[-97.06124,32.834],[-97.06127,32.832]],
    [[-97.06326,32.759],[-97.06298,32.755]]
];

// embed existing array into large JSON definition for polyline
var polylineJSON = {
  "paths": paths,
  "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3857 }
};
Polyline(polylineJSON);
```